# Angular 7 Social Login - Google Signin popup disappearing after clicking

Tags: angular, google-authentication

I am implementing Google Authentication in my Angular 7 project, but am having problems with the popup window that shows when you use the google sign in button.

On a regular chrome tab, the popup where the users login to google with shows up as a blank white popup for a couple of seconds, then just disappears.

This only seems to happen on chrome when I do not have security disabled on the browser. It doesn't happen in Safari either, so I don't really understand what is wrong. I enabled popups and cookies on chrome for all websites, but that did not make a difference.

Lastly, I'm not sure if this is related but when I view the source html on a normal chrome tab (security enabled and everything), I get this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Error</title>
</head>
<body>
<pre>Cannot GET /login</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does the request have any header information associated? A status code? Is there a message in the browser console?

Comment: No errors at all. I checked with one of my other team members and he is not having the problem so it seems to be something with chrome.

Comment: it should be totally possible with chrome. How are you implementing it?

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered this issue before, myself.  It would usually work as expected, but occasionally would display a blank popup window.  You could always try using login via redirect instead of popup method.  (It's stated to be the preferable method via mobile also):

### auth.service.ts

```
import { auth as fbAuth } from 'firebase/app';

async googleLogin() {
  const provider = new fbAuth.GoogleAuthProvider();
  return await this.oAuthLogin(provider);
}

async oAuthLogin(provider) {
  await fbAuth().signInWithRedirect(provider);
  return await fbAuth().getRedirectResult(result => {
  if (result.user != null) {
    var user = result.user;
    console.log(`Welcome back, ${user.displayName}!`);
    }
  })
  .catch(error => console.error(error));

}
```